# How to develop website compatible with mobile using asp.net and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, sidewaffle

i have got to develop website `ASP NET C#` with webpages compatibles with `mobile`

i working with this article **[Visual Studio Tools for Bootstrap](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29385.visual-studio-tools-for-bootstrap.aspx)**

i have installed on project the `SideWaffle.Creator 2017` but i don't find new Item `ASP.NET Scaffolding T4 Files` and the folder `SideWaffle` don't exists on the project

Please help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a [responsive web design](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)

Responsive websites take advantage of CSS media queries to display content based on the screen size.

[Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) is integrated in the Visual Studio 2019 standard templates

Tutorials

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrgPLAvJujE&ab_channel=LernenTech
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vRqz_zUiJTw&ab_channel=IAmTimCorey